# Python merging strings in X positions

Tags: python, string, merge

I am working on some ASCII art, but I have a sub-problem.  I want to merge 2 strings together to create a larger string, but I want to merge the strings so every other letter merges, the left overs would be left where they are.  So, if I have strings `"home"` and `"sweet"` I would want the output to be `"hsowmeet"`; or a longer merge, with what I intend to do as ASCII art, `^^^` and `&&&&&&` would be merged to `^&^&^&&&`.

I know I am off but I was starting something like this:

```
def merge(s1, s2):
  new = s1[1:2] + s2[1:2] + s1[2:2] + s2[2:2]
  return new
```

But so far it looks ugly and isn't doing what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = "^^^"
b = "&&&&&&"

def merge(a, b)
    return "".join((x+y for (x, y) in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue="")))

merge(a, b) # '^&^&^&&&&'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest` with and empty string for the `fillvalue` keyword argument and then massage the return value until it's the string you want.

Here's the output `izip_longest` produces (I make a list out of the result such that it is readable):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> s1 = 'home'
>>> s2 = 'sweet'
>>> list(izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))
[('h', 's'), ('o', 'w'), ('m', 'e'), ('e', 'e'), ('', 't')]
```

Now you simply have to concatenate all the strings (which have length one or zero). One solution is

```
>>> ''.join(sum(izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''), ()))
'hsowmeeet'
```

Alternatively, just use a regular `for` loop:

```
>>> result = ''
>>> for x,y in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''):
...     result += x + y
... 
>>> result
'hsowmeeet'
```

Comment: Using `sum` or building a string with repeated `+=` creates numerous intermediate and ever larger objects before the final result is created.  It probably doesn't matter much with a small task like this but it's worth pointing out that the algorithm is less efficient than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def merge_words(*words):
    return ''.join(c for tup in zip_longest(*words) for c in tup if c)
```

Examples:

```
>>> merge_words('abc', '123456789')
'a1b2c3456789'
>>> merge_words('red', 'rover')
'rreodver'
>>> merge_words('Python', 'merging', 'strings')
'Pmsyettrrhgioinnnggs'
```

Note:  If using Python 2 change `zip_longest` to its old name `izip_longest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools`.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def merge(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([i+j for i,j in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue='')])
```

In python 3.x, it is `zip_longest` instead of `izip_longest`